# Create an applescript / automator workflow that excludes certain file names

Tags: applescript, finder, automator

I want to make an automator folder action that excludes file names with certain words in them, eg:

move all files to /folder x except those containing the words "Screen Shot"

The actual actions work fine I just need the script or automator actions to exclude the files.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [apple.se].


Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use “Filter Finder Items” and set the criteria to be “None of the following are true”: “Name contains Screen Shot”. I just did a quick test with “Choose a Folder”, “Get Folder Contents” and then “Filter Finder Items” and the Results contain only files that do not contain the word I specified.

Comment: That worked really well, thanks for a prompt response. Sorry @brasofilo , I'm new to stack overflow